# How to rewrite the rule in .htaccess to specific url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

Normally when load the URL http://www.example.com/ it goes to http://www.example.com/index.php.

I have to rewrite the url http://www.example.com/something into http://www.example.com/index.php/something

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\.]+) http://www.example.com/index.php/$1 [NC]`

causes loop

Comment: Where did you get stuck in your research?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\.]+) http://www.example/index.php/$1 [NC]` causes loop

Comment: Yes, it probably would. Now, did you look at the rewrite log? Did you come across L or END flags in any similar questions? How would you differentiate the regex from not matching `index.php` else? Why not use a fixed list of matchable basenames? Or use the commonplace RewriteCond to skip existing files? Or why not just FallbackResource? Please be more detailed why none of the thousands of existing questions were applicable.

Answer (score 0):

That loop happened because you don't exclude the target `index` from the `Rewriterule` so you redirect to index then redirect again and again .

Make it like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^(index|$)  index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

That was internally redirecting a request `/something` to `/index.php/something` and if you need to redirect it externally let me know to change accordingly .